# How to highlight a table td in angular 2

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

So basically, I have a table like this

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Date</td>
<td>Time</td>
<tr>
<table>
```

and in this table I want both date and time clickable. When I click on the date it gets highlighted and I can edit the date and at that time the time will be disabled. And the same thing happens when I click time.

Comment: No idea how you implemented your date/time pickers and with what you posted I assume you can use `ng-click="dateClicked"` / `ng-click="timeClicked"` on the relevant elements and within that possibly add/remove `class="highlighted"` on the `td` as needed. Try that and post the code and actual markup if you have issues with the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you work with angular 2 before, you would need some boolean variables that turn true/false in the onclick function you provide for those.

Have a conditional css class that exists only when some boolean is true.